# Asynchronous Call in Meteor Router Flickering Other Template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Ok, maybe I am going about this the wrong way. I am new to meteor and am used to building my apps in express. I have a route to /myaccount. Before rendering any templates I am calling an asynchronous method that checks if the user is an admin. The method is on the server. I tried putting the admin check in onBeforeAction, but I got the same result. What happens is that the login template flickers quickly on the screen before the admin template is loaded. Anyone know how to fix this so the login screen does not flicker on screen before the admin template is loaded? Here's my route:

```
Router.route('/myaccount', function() {
    var _this = this;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if(user) {
        Meteor.call('checkIfAdmin', user.username, function(err, isAdmin){
            if(isAdmin) {
                _this.render('admin');
            } else{
                _this.render('myaccount');
            }
        });
    } else{
        this.render('login');
    }
});
```

What I find strange is that in the iron router docs it says this about onBeforeAction in regards to their example of checking if a user is an admin:

"If the user is not logged in, the route function will never get called"

But the flickering that happened when I used onBeforeAction lead me to believe that it was calling the route function.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure I have the solution but I have still some remarks.

First if you are running this code on the server, your meteor.call is effectively asynchronous. And I do not know what happens at the end of your function for the rendering template. Maybe it renders your precedent template, that is to say login ?

But if you want to avoid the flickering of a template the time iron-router is working, the best thing to do is, I think,  add a loading template :

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

<template name='loading'>
    // some css to render a 'loading feature'
</template>
```

So when you want to go on admin you will have this loading screen instead of login.

For the verification, it is true that I would use a hook or a plugin with onBeforeAction to do such thing as verification, I think it is cleaner with iron-router than a method call.

Comment: I did add loadingTemplate but I have a suspicion that it will only show the loading template when using waitOn while subscribing to a publication but maybe it could work for a method. I also thought about changing things up in onBeforeAction and render the loading template and then when the method has resolved load the appropriate template.